# How can I access an element of an array in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I'm new in JQUERY and trying AJAX.I need to access the array so i can put the element on my html table. btw the array comes from my backend.

the elements in the **data array** are:

```
[1990, "098765", "094561", "098123", "097612"]
```

I tried the usual way but it wont work, How to do it right?
really need help

**my Jquery code:**

```
 $('#trigger').click(function(){
            var send = $('#myselect').val();
            $.ajax({

                data:{
                  sent: send
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/delinquincy'
            })
            .done(function(data){
              console.log(data)
              var q1=data[1]
              var q2=data[2]
              var q3=data[3]
              var q4=data[4]

              $('#q1').html(q1)
              $('#q2').html(q2)
              $('#q3').html(q3)
              $('#q4').html(q4)
            })
          })
```

This is where I put the elements of the array,

my **HTML Table**:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="subtable">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Quarter</th>
                    <th scope="col">O.R.number</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1st Quarter</td>
                    <td id="q1"> </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary subbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submodal" id="pay" data-row-val="" >Pay</button></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>2nd Quarter</td>
                    <td id="q2"> </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary subbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submodal" id="pay" data-row-val="" >Pay</button></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>3rd Quarter</td>
                    <td id="q3"> </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary subbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submodal" id="pay" data-row-val="" >Pay</button></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>4th Quarter</td>
                    <td id="q4"> </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary subbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submodal" id="pay" data-row-val="" >Pay</button></td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: What is the problem? You are correctly accessing it

Comment: What is the result of conolse log? Do you have any errors or whatever?

Comment: waht shows console.log in your cosnole ?

Comment: When I console.log(q1) the result is another element but not from the data array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have no `dataType` set on the request, the response will always come as a string, not as a ready to use javascript array. Use

```
data = JSON.parse(data)
```

before

```
$('#q1').html( data[0] )
```

or add

```
dataType: "json",
```

to your AJAX request.